# What is the recommended way to share static data in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My use case is that I have a large list of subnets which cover things like employee LANs, VPNs, office LANs, guest LANs, etc.  They are not managed in AWS since the end-points aren't actually in the VPC.

However, I would like to use them in security groups to grant access to internal resources.

What is the best way to encode these into TF in a way that is easy to re-use?  Should I create a module that is just shared with everyone?  Is it better to use remote state?  Is there a provider that is well suited for this sort of application?

Comment: Depending upon the complexity of their structure, it sounds like they could simply be input variables in HCL format (simpler), or robust external data (more complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation sounds similar to the use-cases given in the section [Data-only Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html#data-only-modules) in the Terraform documentation page [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html).

How exactly you'd achieve it would depend on whether the information you need is already published somewhere that a Terraform data source could retrieve it from. There are various data sources available across many providers for fetching information about e.g. AWS VPCs/subnets, but the system you're using to manage these non-cloud networks might not have such a convenient integration point.

In that case, there are two more general options to consider:

- If this data will change infrequently and only by intentional administrative action (rather than dynamically based on arbitrary events) then it might be simplest to just hard-code the data directly into a Terraform module as a literal value. This would be a particularly extreme case of a "data-only module" that doesn't even include any data sources, and would instead probably just have some `output` blocks and possibly `local` blocks depending on whether you need some logic to project the data into a convenient shape for the module caller.
- If you can arrange for the data to be uploaded to some accessible HTTP server in JSON format then [the `hashicorp/http` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest) has a data source called just `http` which can retrieve text-based data from an arbitrary HTTP or HTTPS URL. If you have that data published in JSON, for example, then you could use [the `http` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) along with [the `jsondecode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsondecode.html) in your data-only module to get the data into a Terraform-consumable data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think terraform Data Sources can help you. It can gather resource information defined outside of Terraform. [Terraform Data Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html)